# X11 forwarding not working on MAC OS Mojave

Tags: linux, macos, x11-forwarding

I'm having trouble getting x11 forwarding when I ssh into a linux machine. When I do ssh -X username@serveraddress, I get the following error appearing after I successfully login: /usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/username/.Xauthority . I have tried to follow the fixes suggested to this problem on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work.

I have tried editing ~/.ssh/config so that it looks like this:

```
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

This does not fix the problem. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.